# Injected service not resolved only for Delete action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a controller the beginning of which looks like this:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class PersonsController : BaseController
```

`BaseController` looks like this so far:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    public BaseController(CompanyDbContext dbContext)
    {
        Db = dbContext;
    }

    protected CompanyDbContext Db;
}
```

`PersonsController` has a few gets, a post, a put, and a delete. Everything except the `Delete` action works fine, there are no problems resolving the injected `CompanyDbContext`.

The `Delete` action looks like this:

```
[HttpDelete("{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int id)
{
    var pers = await Db.Persons.SingleOrDefaultAsync(p => p.PersonId == id);
    if (pers == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    Db.Remove(pers);
    await Db.SaveChangesAsync();
    return Ok();
}
```

Yet when I do a delete request:

```
public async Task DeletePersonAsync(int id)
{
    var resp = await _client.DeleteAsync($"api/Persons/{id}");
    resp.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
}
```

where `_client` is an `HttpClient`, I get the following error:

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type
>   'AcmeSoft.Api.Data.CompanyDbContext' while attempting to activate
>   'AcmeSoft.Api.Controllers.PersonsController'

I am using the default, built-in DI that comes with a new MVC Core 2.0 project. I register the context service in class `Startup` as follows:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<CompanyDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
    services.AddMvc();
}
```

Yet the service resolves properly for all actions but `Delete`. What could be wrong here? Where have I gone wrong?

For those that like long questions, the entire `PersonsController` is as follows:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class PersonsController : BaseController
{
    public PersonsController(CompanyDbContext dbContext) : base(dbContext)
    {
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        var persons = Db.Persons.ToList();
        return Ok(persons);
    }

    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get(int id)
    {
        var pers = await Db.Persons.SingleOrDefaultAsync(p => p.PersonId == id);
        if (pers == null)
        {
            return Ok(null);
        }
        return Ok(pers);
    }

    [HttpGet("GetByIdNumber/{idNumber}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetByIdNumber(string idNumber)
    {
        var pers = await Db.Persons.SingleOrDefaultAsync(e => e.IdNumber == idNumber);
        if (pers == null)
        {
            return Ok(null);
        }

        return Ok(pers);
    }

    [HttpGet("PersonEmployees")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PersonEmployees()
    {
        var emps = await Db.PersonEmployees.ToListAsync();
        return Ok(emps);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] Person person)
    {
        Db.Add(person);
        await Db.SaveChangesAsync();
        return Ok(person);
    }

    [HttpPut]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Put([FromBody] Person person)
    {
        Db.Update(person);
        await Db.SaveChangesAsync();
        return Ok(person);
    }

    [HttpDelete("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int id)
    {
        var pers = await Db.Persons.SingleOrDefaultAsync(p => p.PersonId == id);
        if (pers == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        Db.Remove(pers);
        await Db.SaveChangesAsync();
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

All actions except delete work.

ADDED: The stack trace shown on the developer error page is:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'AcmeSoft.Api.Data.CompanyDbContext' while attempting to activate 'AcmeSoft.Api.Controllers.PersonsController'.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, Boolean isDefaultParameterRequired)
   at lambda_method(Closure , IServiceProvider , Object[] )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerActivatorProvider.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<CreateActivator>b__0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerFactoryProvider.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<CreateControllerFactory>g__CreateController|0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>d__14.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>d__22.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>d__17.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>d__15.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.<Invoke>d__7.MoveNext()
```

Comment: @juunas I have done so, but if there was something wrong with the service registration, surely the service would not resolve for any actions?

Comment: this is odd. We both know that error is associated with a service not being registered, yet you have shown that you do register the context and also that it works for the other actions. Here is a long shot. manually register the context as well in the service configuration.  `services.AddScoped<CompanyDbContext, CompanyDbContext>();` and see what happens.

Comment: @Nkosi Nope, even the extra registration didn't work. I'll create a smaller project with only delete in mind and see what happens.

Comment: This was going to be my next suggestion. Let me know how that works out.